# Is there a way to disable user interaction for button embedded in the navigationBar (navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem)?

Tags: ios, uikit

I need a button in the navigationBar but it should not be "clickable".
I have found that I can simply disable the button by setting the .isEnabled property to false, but this has a visual effect on the button (makes it appear grey and very faint) which I don't want. So is there a way to apply the isUserInteractionEnabled property to a navigation bar button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should create button like this globally in your `UIViewController`, so later you can change `isUserInteractionEnabled` to **true** or **false**:

```
lazy var rightBarButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourAssetName"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeController), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

Than you should add your button as `customView` to your `barButtonItem`:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarButton)
```

And when you need to disable `isUserInteractionEnabled`, just call:

```
rightBarButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

**Hope this one will help you!**